# Calculated column for difference between ordered cells Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

What would be the calculated column formula for trying to calculate the thickness (difference between cells of different depths) for each PLACENAME.
See table below. The thickness I am trying to calculate is the difference between each depth increment.

[image]

Comment: Hey FLgeo! How about that Bama game? :) Can you give some expected output? I think I know what you want but want to be sure. WOuld it be the thickness - the thickness of the next depth over the placename?

Comment: @FLgeo - How did you calculate thickness for the last rows of Placenames A & B?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is already sorted, there is no need to place row numbers based on the ranking (order) of the `Depth`. If the rows were unsorted, we would need to use `Rank()` to apply a sort order based on the `Depth` and `PLACENAME`. Depending on what row and what direction you want to do the difference to be calculated, you can use the following formulas:

```
[Thickness] - First([Thickness]) over (Intersect([PLACENAME],Next([Depth]))) AS [DifferenceBelow]

[Thickness] - First([Thickness]) over (Intersect([PLACENAME],Previous([Depth]))) AS [DifferenceAbove]
```

You will get the following results:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

@FLgeo- As per your question, the below custom expression should calculate the difference of depths for each Placename.

```
Abs([Depth] - Sum([Depth]) OVER (Intersect(Next([RowID]),[PlaceName])))
```

*Note: 'RowID' column is added for computation purpose. This need not be displayed in the table.*

[image]

Question - Your table shows thickness value for the last rows of Placenames A & B, how did you calculate those?

Comment: Who ever gave a negative vote for this answer, could you please explain why? This would help in improving my answer. Simply giving a negative vote wouldn't help. Also, post your interpretation of the question/solution so that it might help users.Thank you!

Comment: Interesting approach using absolute value. We understood the question differently but I see where your methods were.